# How to name branch in gitflow for 'update/upgrade third-party packages'?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm working on update npm libraries (third-party packages) but I dont know to name branch: feature, hotfix, another?.

What do you recommends me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be a feature branch, used to isolate a development effort.

In your case: `feature/upgradetp`, to test in your own branch the upgrade of third-party packages.
If that works, then you can merge in `develop` for integration testing, and finally `master` for release.

---

Atlassian has a nice presentation of [feature branch as part of a workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow):

> The core idea behind the Feature Branch Workflow is that all feature development should take place in a dedicated branch instead of the main branch.
>
> This encapsulation makes it easy for multiple developers to work on a particular feature without disturbing the main codebase.
> It also means the main branch will never contain broken code, which is a huge advantage for continuous integration environments.

Same idea with [Mergify's decription of feature branch](https://blog.mergify.com/feature-branch-a-quick-walk-through-git-workflow/).

Another name is "topic branch", used with [gitworkflow](https://github.com/rocketraman/gitworkflow?tab=readme-ov-file#continuous-integration-done-right), that I [present here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57175304/6309).

Comment: Would be nice with a reference or an explanation why to use "feature" here. But I appreciate it anyway. Thanks

Comment: @DennisDyallo I have edited the answer to add some references.